# Где скачать базу данных Northwind?

Tags: sql

Где скачать базу данных Northwind? Все возможное перерыл - не нашел.

Answer (score 3):

[Получение образцов баз данных для примеров кода ADO.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases)